# Unable to polyfill Object.fromEntries in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, babeljs, babel-polyfill, core-js

I have a simple Ember app and I need to polyfill `Object.fromEntries` in a component.

For reference, I use Safari 12.1.1 that supports `fromEntries` natively and Safari 11.1.1 that does not.

AFAIK, all I should need is a proper `ember-cli-build.js` config.

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me why the following tweaks do not properly polyfill the function:

```js
const app = new EmberApp(defaults, {

  'ember-cli-babel': {
    // supposedly should inject core-js/stable into app
    // @see https://github.com/babel/ember-cli-babel#polyfill
    includePolyfill: true,
  },

  babel: {
    // should replace injected core-js/stable with imports
    // that are not natively supported by config/targets.js
    // @see https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins-entry
    useBuiltIns: 'entry',

    // explicitly use corejs v3 per babel-preset-env docs
    corejs: 3,

    // force inclusion of fromEntries regardless of config/targets.js
    include: [
      'es.object.from-entries',
    ],
  },

  //...
});
```

I can see it's there: https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/v7.5.5/packages/babel-preset-env/src/polyfills/corejs3/built-in-definitions.js#L265

---

Package versions:

- ember-source@3.7.2
- ember-cli@3.5.0
- ember-cli-babel@7.5.0
- @babel/core@7.5.5
- core-js@3.2.1

Comment: This looks correct to me. Make sure you're stopping and re-starting your `ember serve` command to register the changes to this special file. Could you expand on the error you're seeing? Just doesn't work in safari?

Comment: @jrjohnson Yeah, I've been restarting after each config change, reloading without cache. It seems pretty straightforward, however when I use `Object.fromEntries`, whatever my polyfill config, Safari 11 says "Object.fromEntries is not a function" and Safari 12 works fine on the page that uses it. When I use Safari dev tools I can see v12 has a native `Object.fromEntries` implementation and v11 does not define it. Maybe my assumptions about how these options work are wrong. There is no definitive Ember guide on this case that I could find.

Comment: To be clear, I can see the effect of changing the config, e.g. if I change `useBuiltIns` to `usage` then the build fails to find some `core-js` import (which seems weird also, but is a different case) and if I add a non-existent polyfill as an `include` then it throws a build error as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

What does your `config/targets.js` file look like? I'm wondering if the polyfill is not included because your browser config only includes the most recent version of Safari so Ember and Babel are being smart and not shipping the extra code.

The [default for new apps](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-new-output/blob/v3.10.1/config/targets.js):

```
'use strict';

const browsers = [
  'last 1 Chrome versions',
  'last 1 Firefox versions',
  'last 1 Safari versions'
];

const isCI = !!process.env.CI;
const isProduction = process.env.EMBER_ENV === 'production';

if (isCI || isProduction) {
  browsers.push('ie 11');
}

module.exports = {
  browsers
};
```

Includes IE11 only in production builds. If you're testing Safari 11 locally it wouldn't be included in that list.

Try changing it to the last 2 versions of Safari.

```
const browsers = [
  'last 1 Chrome versions',
  'last 1 Firefox versions',
  'last 2 Safari versions'
];
```

And see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem going on except IE11 is in my list and it still can't use the `Object.fromEntries` method.

So the problem here is that:

1. Ember/Broccoli uses a funky module system that makes `useBuiltIns: 'entry'` and `useBuiltIns: 'usage'` impossible. As of writing, this issue hasn't been worked on yet. https://github.com/babel/ember-cli-babel/issues/298
2. The include syntax basically doesn't work. https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8932

The solution I found was to basically just bypass the babel/ember/broccoli system just like `@babel/polyfil` deprecation notice says to do *sorta*.

1. Remove all the new `babel` stuff in the `ember-cli.build.js` file that you added to try and get it to work, but leave the `includePolyfill: true`.
2. `npm install core-js --save-dev` to install corejs directly
3. Import the exact polyfill that explodes.

```
import "core-js/es/object/from-entries";
```

This is the only way i've gotten it to work.